# UFT 14.52 spying Java object but not adding it

Tags: hp-uft

Am since long trying to add objects from a Java based application in UFT 14.52 but not able to.

Made sure that all hooks are added to env vars. UFT is behaving weird ie it spies the object correctly, but the moment I try adding it doesn't. In some circumstances, it does add it but then again doesn't highlight it. Even though when I try adding the same, it adds exactly the same object but again doesn't highlights.

I have tried
. Reinstalling UFT
. Reinstalling java 1.8 (202)
. Enabling and disabling plugins
. Installed UFT with admin privileges
( In all the cases, am launching UFT first)
. Deleting and resetting java env vars

The machine am on has security policies in place and I can not do much modification to system or registry except the user ones.

Am able to add Windows, wpf or web objects. It is the java am having issues with.

Any help or insight Will be helpful. 
Good night.

Comment: we skipped uft 14.52 due many bugs with bpt. You could give a try installating UFT 14.53.... Did you tried Hover Mode?

Comment: Yes. I did, but did not help.

Comment: The application is self contained, ie has its own jre and probably creates its own JVM . Can this be the cause ?

Comment: Nah I dont think so, my company also has an self contained application with own JRE. Did you tried deselecting the Java Add-In? Can UFT recognize the application?

Comment: Yes as Windows, wintree etc

Comment: We had a similar problem. Uft was adding Eclipse 4.6 Objects to the repo but it did not add the Objects of an Application called Teamcenter which was also based on Eclipse 4.6 (Teamcenter 12 )

Microfocus provided a special patch for it and then it ran

Comment: So how did you manage to add it finally ? Updated uft to 14.53 ?

Comment: Can you please provide the uft version and patch version ?

Comment: As Jonas suggested, 14.52 is filled with bugs. We had to downgrade to 14.03 and it worked. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 
Your system display setting are set to 100%
and
your browser zoom % set to 100%

I see similar problem with Java application and after setting both setting it worked like charm.